# Yii DefaultController's action with a dash

Tags: php, yii

this is my current directory structure for my modules

[image]

in my **DefaultController.php** i have this

```
<?php

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    //set default action if nessesary
    public $defaultAction = 'index'; //default is index

    /**
     * Declares class-based actions.
     */
    public function actions() {

        // page action renders "static" pages stored under '/views/default/pages'
        // They can be accessed via: index.php?r=default/page&view=FileName
        return array(
            'pages' => array('class' => 'CViewAction'),
        );
    }

    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $this->render('index');
    }

    /**
    * Catch all action - used as a workaround to support dashed action names like my-action => actionMyAction
    * @param string $action Action that was not found within this controller
    */
    public function missingAction($action){
            $action = explode('-', $action);
            $action = array_map('strtolower', $action);
            $action = array_map('lcfirst', $action);
            $action = implode('',$action);

            if(method_exists($this,'action'.$action) || array_key_exists('action'.$action, $this->actions())){
                    $this->setAction($action);
                    $this->run($action); 
            }else{
                    throw new CHttpException(404, Yii::t('main','Action "{action}" does not exist in "{controller}".', array(
                            '{action}' => 'action'.$action,
                            '{controller}' => get_class($this),
                    )));
            }
    }

    public function actionLoanCalculator()
    {
        $model=new CalculatorsForm();

        // uncomment the following code to enable ajax-based validation
        /*
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='loan-calculator-form')
        {
            echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
        */


        if(isset($_POST['loan-calculator-form']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['loan-calculator-form'];

            if($model->validate())
            {
               // form inputs are valid, do something here
               print_r($_REQUEST);
               return;
            }
        }

        $this->render('loan-calculator',array('model'=>$model));

    }
}
```

and this is my Url Manager

```
'<view:(about|terms|faq|privacy)>' => 'site/page',
'<action:(contact|login|logout)>' => 'site/<action>',
'<action:(loan-calculator)>' => 'calculators/default/pages/view/<action>',
'<action:(registration|create)>' => 'user/<action>',
'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
```

i tried adding the **missingAction()** function in my default controller to allow actions' with dashes. but i am still getting this error when i go to **domain.com/dev/loan-calculator**

Error im getting is

```
Undefined variable: model
```

it goes to the loan-calculator.php in views. but doesn't go thru `function actionLoanCalculator()` in my default controller. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

With your UrlManager configuration, you use the 'page' action to render the loanCalculator. This is is for static pages, no model is loaded beforhand. It looks like your view expects a model to be loaded by the controller, hence the error.

I think you redirect in the third line of your urlManager conf  should be

```
'<action:(loan-calculator)>' => 'calculators/default/loanCalculator',
```

then you would not need the catch all. Or use

'' => 'calculators/default/loan-Calculator',

and let your missingActions method work.
But maybe you should test your controller by simply entering the route you want, before using the urlManager. The route for a module action looks like this:
`moduleID/controllerID/actionID`, so in your case:

```
calculators/default/loan-calculator
```

A different way to handle actions with dashes could be implementing the `beforeAction()` method, and strip dashes from the action id there.

Comment: ah, didn't know pages was for static files. now i sort of got it to work. `http://localhost/dev/calculators/default/loan-calculator` but how to make it work on `http://localhost/dev/loan-calculator`. on this 2nd url i get this error '404 Action "actionview" does not exist in "DefaultController".'

Comment: tried this `http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/404/hyphenation-of-routes-in-url-management/` but i'm getting this error `
Error 404
Unable to resolve the request "calculators/loanCalculator".`

Comment: This seems like a new question.